# ocaml - deoptionalize a list: is there a simpler way?

Tags: ocaml

I have written a function to deoptionalize an integer list and I would like to know if there is a better way to write it.

```
let deoptionalize (lst:'a option list) : 'a list =
    List.map ~f:(fun x -> match x with Some x -> x | None -> assert false)
                    (List.filter ~f:(fun x -> x <> None) lst)
;;
```

In the assignment I am currently working its using map and filter is a must.

Comment: Are you using the `Core` library?

Comment: Yes I am using the core library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that a "hand-coded" solution (i.e. without `map` and `filter`) is easier to read, but if you really need to use them, here you go:

It seems that you are using the `Core` library. If so, I think your solution is not so bad, but can be written a bit more compact:

```
let deoptionalize lst = 
    List.filter ~f:(is_some) lst
    |> List.map ~f:(function | Some x -> x | None -> assert false)
```

If you don't mind warnings (which I discourage you to do), you can even leave out some more:

```
let deoptionalize lst = 
    List.filter ~f:(is_some) lst
    |> List.map ~f:(fun (Some x) -> x)
```

Actually, `Core` provides `filter_map` (thanks @Ramon Snir for the hint) which combines both, so you can use:

```
let deopt lst = 
    List.filter_map ~f:(fun x -> x) lst;;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Core`, but shouldn't there be a `List.choose` function? See F#'s: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353456.aspx

Comment: @RamonSnir Thanks, it actually does! It's called `filter_map`.

Comment: Doesn't filter_map do the opposite of deoptionalize? `filter_map f l is the sublist of l containing only elements for which f returns Some e.` (Quoted from https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.60.00/doc/core/#Std.List)

Comment: As far as I can judge it, it does exactly what you need. It looks which elements are `Some ...` and discards the `None`s.

Comment: Core provides `Fn.id` by the way, so `List.filter_map ~f:Fn.id` is sufficient.

Comment: The normal (non-Core) Standard Library now also has a `List.filter_map` since OCaml 4.08 and so it can be done like this: `List.filter_map Fun.id your_option_list`

Answer (score 3):

In your case, I prefer doing in this way:

```
let deoptionalize l =
  let rec deopt acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | None::tl -> deopt acc tl
    | Some x::tl -> deopt (x::acc) tl
  in 
  deopt [] l
```

It is more clear and tail-recursive and performance is better

Answer (score 0):

Another solution,

```
let deoptionalize l = 
    List.concat  @@ List.map (function | None -> [] | Some x -> [x]) l
```