# List option to list in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a function that returns a (char list) list option, and I'm trying to get the size of the list:

```
let c = recherche m ledico in
  match c with
    | None -> Printf.printf "Non."
    | Some [] -> Printf.printf "Oui."
    | _ ->
      let n = List.length c in
(...)
```

`recherche` is the function that returns me the `(char list) list option`, and it can return either `None`, `Some []`, or `Some [[...] ; ... ; [...]]`. How do I find this length? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674947/ocaml-deoptionalize-a-list-is-there-a-simpler-way) solution but it didn't work:

```
Error: The function applied to this argument has type 'a list -> 'a list
This argument cannot be applied with label ~f
```

How do I get the size of a list option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give the list a name.

```
| Some l -> let n = List.length l in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a function to `'a option`, you just need a function that works on values of type `'a`, and a value to return when the input is `None`. There is a function in the Core library named `value_map` that does this. The basic implementation is very simple:

```
let value_map x default f =
    match x with
    | None -> default
    | Some sx -> f sx
```

In your case, you need to choose a default. The function you want to apply is `List.length`.