# Making helper function that separates 'a list from 'a option list

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a helper function that can take a list like [Some 3; None; Some 5; Some 10] = [3;5;10] and output just the integers, as shown. However I'm getting a parsing error and don't know what to do about it.

apfold.ml", line 32, characters 11-12:
Parse error: [opt_when_expr] expected after [patt_as_patt_opt] (in [match_case0]

The line number is referring to the line with | [Some] [int] = [int]

Here is the function thus far:

```
let rec difference (thelist:'a option list) : 'a list =
    match thelist with
    | [Some] [int] -> [int]
;;
```

The function difference gets plugged into this:

```
let deoptionalize (lst:'a option list) : 'a list =
    List.filter ~f:(fun lst -> difference)
;;
```

Although, if there were a way to do the deoptionalize function without using a helper function, I would very much appreciate any assistance in figuring that out.

Comment: It can contain None. What would you recommend using instead? In the pset I'm limited to List.map, List.filter, and List.fold_right

Comment: I can however use previous functions that I've implemented, although I don't see any of them being useful for this function and I don't want to post 400 lines of code just for this function.

Comment: Actually, `List.filter` doesn't seem useful in any case. Its output is always some subset of the input (it doesn't transform the values). It was `List.map` that I was thinking of. The output of `List.map` is always the same length as the input. By elimination, this suggests you should look at `List.fold_right`.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using a combination of List.map and List.filter. I could remove the None's from the set using filter, then use List.map to change the types from Some int to int. Thoughts on that?

Comment: That will work, great idea. The first helper fun is going to have type `'a option -> bool`. The second would have type `'a option -> 'a`.

Comment: Do I need the helper function at all if I go the filter/map route? I was thinking of bypassing the helper function altogether.

Comment: You need functions for sure. The first parameter of both `List.filter` and `List.map` is a function. But they could be simple enough to write inline. That is just a style choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from the `[Some] [int]`: this is not a valid OCaml pattern.

About using List.filter then List.map, it is quite useless to go two times through your list. You can just use a `List.fold_right`:

```
let remove_options l = List.fold_right
    (fun x result ->
     match x with
     | Some i -> i :: result
     | None -> result )
    l []
```

This way you go through your list once and avoid allocating an intermediate list.

Comment: If the order of the integers in your list doesn't matter, you can use `List.fold_left` instead (be careful: you'll have to change the orders of your arguments). It will put your list in reverse order but it will be tail-recursive and hence less memory consuming.

Comment: Could you explain what the 1 is supposed to represent? I don't understand the function of it after remove_options and at the end of the match.

Comment: It's not a 1, it's a l (lowercase L). `List.fold_right` takes 3 arguments: a function (lines 2 to 5), a list (`l`) and a starting value accumulator (`[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeffrey Scofield and some thinking of my own, we have determined that a great way to do this would be to use List.map and List.filter to separate None from Some and then extract the int from within. The inner function can either be a helper function or an inline function; that is a style preference.

Answer (score 0):

Since OCaml version 4.08, this can now be done very easily by combining the `List.filter_map` [(doc)](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/List.html#VALfilter_map) and `Fun.id` [(doc)](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/Fun.html#VALid) functions from the Standard Library:

```
List.filter_map Fun.id [Some 3; None; Some 5; Some 10];;

(* returns [3; 5; 10] *)
```

---

Related question, if using the Base/Core libraries: [ocaml - deoptionalize a list: is there a simpler way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674947/ocaml-deoptionalize-a-list-is-there-a-simpler-way)